# Unity ObjectPool<T> CountActive is not decreasing after a destroy is called

Tags: unity, c#, object-pools

I have made a loop to spawn and despawn a basic sphere gameobject. The issue is that when spawning goes over the max size, it does not decrease the `ActiveCount` when removed. Is this a Unity bug or am I missing something?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Pool;

public class Monopooltest : MonoBehaviour {
  public int capacity = 1;
  public int maxSize = 3;
  public ObjectPool<GameObject> pool;
  public List<GameObject> activeObjs;
  public int active; 
  public int inactive;
  private void Update() {
    active = pool.CountActive;
    inactive = pool.CountInactive;
  }
  public GameObject prefab;

  protected Coroutine loopCo;
  public IEnumerator Loop() {
    while(true) {
      Spawn(5);
      yield return null;
      Despawn(5);
      yield return null;
    }
  }
  
  private void Awake() {
    pool = new(
      () => Instantiate(prefab),
      (obj) => { obj.SetActive(true); activeObjs.Add(obj); },
      (obj) => { obj.SetActive(false); activeObjs.Remove(obj);},
      (obj) => Destroy(obj),
      true,
      capacity,
      maxSize
    );
  }
  private void OnEnable() {
    loopCo = StartCoroutine(Loop());
  }
  private void OnDisable() {
    StopCoroutine(loopCo);
    while(activeObjs.Count > 0) {
      Despawn();
    }
    loopCo = null;
  }
  void Spawn() {
    pool.Get();
  }
  public void Despawn() {
    var obj = activeObjs.Pop();
    pool.Release(obj);
  }
  void Spawn(int num) {
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      Spawn();
    }
  }
  void Despawn(int num) {
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      Despawn();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can find the source code for ObjectPool here](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/ObjectPool/ObjectPools.cs).

Taking a look at the code, we can see `CountAll` (from which `CountActive` is computed on demand) is incremented when a new instance of the pooled type is created, but never decremented anywhere, even when `m_ActionOnDestroy` is invoked.

We could fix this with a one-line change:

```
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public void Release(T element)
    {
        if (m_CollectionCheck && (m_List.Count > 0 || m_FreshlyReleased != null))
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(element, m_FreshlyReleased)) {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Trying to release an object that has already been released to the pool.");
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < m_List.Count; i++)
            {
                if (ReferenceEquals(element, m_List[i]))
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Trying to release an object that has already been released to the pool.");
            }
        }

        m_ActionOnRelease?.Invoke(element);
        if(m_FreshlyReleased == null)
        {
            m_FreshlyReleased = element;
        }
        else if (CountInactive < m_MaxSize)
        {
            m_List.Add(element);
        }
        else
        {
            m_ActionOnDestroy?.Invoke(element);
            CountAll--;   // Fix to permanent count increase above max size
        }
    }
```

So yes, this looks like a Unity bug worth reporting.

I *could* see this being argued as a deliberate API design choice (albeit not one I'd agree with) along one of three lines:

- The pool can't make any guarantees about what happens to destroyed objects. *It* doesn't hold a reference to them, but others might, so far all it kmows they're still taking up memory and haven't been garbage collected. So, reducing `CountAll`/`CountActive` in this case could be a misleading signal, and they choose to report the most pessimistic/conservative value they can guarantee is not an under-count.
- Hitting the max size is an exceptional case that should be avoided in an app that uses the pool correctly. When objects *are* created above the max, having `CountAll` (and by extension `CountActive` which is calculated from it) stay persistently high afterward makes this issue easy to detect, even after a transient spike of creation and releasing passes. It could be argued the fix above masks the symptom of the issue without addressing the root problem of spawning over max in the first place.

  Okay, but then just add a `CountDestroyed` and subtract that when getting `CountActive`? But now we've increased the memory footprint of every pool to support an out-of-contract use case. Users can implement their own counting in `actionOnDestroy` if they need an accurate count in that case.
- Or maybe either of these fixed is *just* enough to break inlining in some cases and add a measurable cost in performance-critical code even when the max isn't hit? That would be unfortunate.

I don't *agree* with these arguments, but they're pushback you could conceivably get to proposing the fix above — and the only reasons I can imagine it hasn't already been fixed. I'd argue that at the very least, this API design is misleading, and `CountActive` should say `CountActiveOrDestroyed` or explicitly call out this case in the documentation, if a fix like the one above were to be rejected.

Comment: Seems odd to me as well, As an integer overflow could easily occur from an oversight. I decided to just make my own pool with two lists and the same events.

Answer (score 0):

I manage my problem about Unity's Object Pooling system with a way I don't like too much. The code snippet below.

```
private void GenerateByAid() {
    //The number of pooled objects which are in the list
    List<EnemyBlock> li = new List<EnemyBlock>();
    for (int i = 0; i < _poolMax; i++) {
        EnemyBlock eb = _pool.Get();
        li.Add(eb);
    }

    for (int i = li.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        li[i].PushBack2Pool();
        li.RemoveAt(i);
    }
    Debug.Log("List range : " +  li.Count);
}

private void GenarateByTime() {
    //Take instance from the pool in period
    _generatorTimeMeter += Time.deltaTime;
    if (_generatorTimeMeter > _generationTimeInterval) {

        _pool.Get();
        _generatorTimeMeter = 0;
    }
}

void Update() {
    GenarateByTime();

    _numberOfPooled = _pool.CountAll;
    _numberOfActive = _pool.CountActive;
    _numberOfInactive = _pool.CountInactive;
}

void Start() {
    _pool = new ObjectPool<EnemyBlock>(
        CreateElement, 
        GetFromPool, 
        Return2Pool, 
        DestroyWhenOverCapacity, 
        false, 
        _poolCount, 
        _poolMax);
 
    GenerateByAid();

    _numberOfPooled = _pool.CountAll;
    _numberOfActive = _pool.CountActive;
    _numberOfInactive = _pool.CountInactive;
}
```

This gives me the correct numbers and also I can generate them at once and store them as `gameObject.setActive(false)` before I use.